# How to resolve the error 400 using Watson speech to text api

Tags: python, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm trying to import audios (mp3, m4a or flac) into this code in order to access the Watson API and get a transcript.
I've tried with different audio files, extracted from video or recorded directly by windows recorder. All of them with different sizes close to 1 to 12MB.
But always return this error below. I didn't find answers on other websites with similar questions.

```
pip install ibm_watson
apikey = 'xxxx'
url = 'yyyy'

from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import subprocess
import os

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
stt = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator = authenticator)
stt.set_service_url(url)

f= "file_path"
res = stt.recognize(audio=f, content_type='audio/m4a', model='en-US_NarrowbandModel', continuous=True, inactivity_timeout=360).get_result()
```

---

```
ApiException                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-cfbd4e46f426> in <module>()
      3 f= "file_path"
      4 res = stt.recognize(audio=f, content_type='audio/m4a', model='en-US_NarrowbandModel', continuous=True,
----> 5                     inactivity_timeout=360).get_result()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    300                                         status_code=response.status_code)
    301 
--> 302             raise ApiException(response.status_code, http_response=response)
    303         except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    304             logging.exception(self.ERROR_MSG_DISABLE_SSL)

ApiException: Error: Stream was 9 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes., Code: 400 , X-global-transaction-id: 927c7d31-c030-4d71-8998-aa544b1ae111
```

Comment: error shows `Stream was 9 bytes` and `len("file_path")` gives `9`. Probably it needs `audio=open(f, 'rb').read()` instead of `audio=f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but error shows `Stream was 9 bytes` and `len("file_path")` gives `9`.

Probably it needs

```
audio=open(f, 'rb').read()
```

instead of `audio=f`

---

**EDIT:**

Documentation for [recognize()](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#recognize) shows example which uses

```
with open('file_path', 'rb') as audio_file:

    speech_to_text.recognize(audio=audio_file, ...)
```

so it means you may need

```
audio=open(f, 'rb')
```

without `.read()`

---

Full example from documentation:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    authenticator=authenticator
)

speech_to_text.set_service_url('{url}')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'audio-file2.flac'),
               'rb') as audio_file:
    speech_recognition_results = speech_to_text.recognize(
        audio=audio_file,
        content_type='audio/flac',
        word_alternatives_threshold=0.9,
        keywords=['colorado', 'tornado', 'tornadoes'],
        keywords_threshold=0.5
    ).get_result()
print(json.dumps(speech_recognition_results, indent=2))
```

You have to click link [recognize()](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#recognize) and scroll down to see it in documentation.

[image]